# Alembic generates arbitrary type changes for Geometry columns

Tags: python, sqlite, alembic, spatialite, geoalchemy2

I'm working on a project that uses SQLite as a database and Alembic as a database migration tool. It includes spatial data and therefore, spatial extensions and `geoalchemy2` are included in the project. I'm using `autogenerate` command and it detects some changes that don't exist in the geometry columns.

Here is the simplified structure of the project:

```py
    # Model
    sqlite_naming_convention = {
    "ix": "ix_%(column_0_label)s",
    "uq": "uq_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s",
    "ck": "ck_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s",
    "fk": "fk_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s_%(referred_table_name)s",
    "pk": "pk_%(table_name)s",
    }
    Metadata = MetaData(naming_convention=sqlite_naming_convention)
    BaseSpatiaLite = declarative_base(metadata=Metadata)


    class Geometries(BaseSpatiaLite):
        __tablename__ = "Geometries"

        geometry_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        geometry = Column(
            geoalchemy2.types.Geometry(geometry_type="GEOMETRY", srid=4326, management=True),
            nullable=False,
        )
        name = Column(String(length=150), nullable=False)
```

Alembic's `env.py` is as follows:

```py
    # env.py
    ...
    def run_migrations_online():
        connectable = engine_from_config(
            config.get_section(config.config_ini_section),
            prefix="sqlalchemy.",
            poolclass=pool.NullPool,
        )
        # Enables Spatialite extension
        listen(connectable, "connect", load_spatialite)
        # Creates Spatial tables if they don't exist
        create_spatial_tables_for_sqlite(connectable)
        with connectable.connect() as connection:
            context.configure(
                connection=connection,
                target_metadata=target_metadata,
                render_as_batch=True,
                compare_type=True,
            )
    
            with context.begin_transaction():
                context.run_migrations()
```

First migration script which creates the Geometry table:

```py
    ...
    def upgrade():
        op.create_table(
            "Geometries",
            sa.Column("geometry_id", sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
            sa.Column("geometry", geoalchemy2.types.Geometry(management=True), nullable=False),
            sa.Column("name", sa.String(length=150), nullable=False),
            sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint("geometry_id"),
        )
    
    
    def downgrade():
        op.drop_table(
            "Geometries",
        )
```

After this migration script is run, the table is created correctly:

[image: Created Geometry table]

When I run `autogenerate` command again, it should have found no changes. However, it generates a  migration script which has an arbitrary type change:

[image]

```py
    def upgrade():
        with op.batch_alter_table("Geometries", schema=None) as batch_op:
            batch_op.alter_column(
                "geometry",
                existing_type=sa.NUMERIC(),
                type_=geoalchemy2.types.Geometry(srid=4326, management=True),
                nullable=False,
            )
    
    
    def downgrade():
        with op.batch_alter_table("Geometries", schema=None) as batch_op:
            batch_op.alter_column(
                "geometry",
                existing_type=geoalchemy2.types.Geometry(srid=4326, management=True),
                type_=sa.NUMERIC(),
                nullable=True,
            )
```

I know that I might set `compare_type` argument to `False` but I'd like to auto-detect the type changes. Is there any way to tell Alembic that the type of `geometry` column is `Geometry` and there is no change at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I'm sharing it here in case some other people might face this error: (https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/autogenerate.html#comparing-types)

It's possible to implement a custom `compare_type` function and use it in `env.py`. In my case, `geometry` columns were interpreted as `sqlalchemy.Integer` or `sqalchemy.NUMERIC` types. That's why I added an if clause which `returns False` if inspected_type is `NUMERIC` or `Integer` and metadata_type is `geoalchemy2.types.Geometry`.

```
# add it to env.py
def custom_compare_type(
    context, 
    inspected_column, 
    metadata_column, 
    inspected_type, 
    metadata_type
):
# return False if the metadata_type is the same as the inspected_type
# or None to allow the default implementation to compare these
# types. a return value of True means the two types do not
# match and should result in a type change operation.
if (isinstance(inspected_type, NUMERIC) or isinstance(inspected_type, Integer)) and isinstance(
    metadata_type, Geometry
):
    return False

return None
```

When you change `compare_type=True` to `compare_type=custom_compare_type`, Alembic should drop detecting arbitrary type changes for `geometry` columns!

**Note:** Alembic still detects a nullability change but it's not related to `compare_type` issue.